# PDO PHP Error , Now sure how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, notice

I am getting the following errors:

> **Notice**: Array to string conversion in line 371
>
> **Warning**: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens on line 371

The code which generate this error is below :

```
// update member file report...
$sql = 'UPDATE memberFileReports SET membersAdded =?, membersCanceled=?, errors=?, dateProcessed=?, totalProcessed=? WHERE id = ?';

$totalToProcess = $membersAdded + $membersCanceled + $totalErrorCount;

$userarray = array($membersAdded,$membersCanceled,$totalErrorCount,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),$totalToProcess,$fileDataReportId);

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array($userarray));
```

Please help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$stmt->execute(array($userarray));` to `$stmt->execute($userarray);`.  Since `$userarray` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in a new array.  By wrapping it in a new array like your code was, PDO gets sent 1 parameter when it expected all 6.  This is why the error generated said "*number of bound variables* does not match *number of tokens*".

Comment: Thanks thats should be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

User array variable is set as an array on creation. And on executed os added to other array.

Remove the duplicated array declaration or the execute function thinks theres only one parameter.